# Xamarin.forms Navigation page not showing in add item visual studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, cross-platform

I am creating a Visual Studio Cross-Platform Xamarin.Forms application (C#) and I would like to add a Navigation Page to the solution. When I press add, Content Page, Tabbed Page, and Master Detail Page all show up, but not Navigation Page.

[image]

This is extremely strange and frustrating...Anybody know a solution?

I have Xamarin installed and updated to the latest version.

Comment: A navigation page in itself isn't really a thing. Just go into your `App.xaml.cs` (or wherever you want the navigation page) and wrap your current page in a `new NavigationPage(new YourCurrentPage());`.

Comment: So for example if I want the Navigation Page on a page called test, I go into test.xaml.cs and write NavigationPage(new test()); ?

Comment: It’s hard to say when I don’t know the details of your requirements. I guess it’s more clear when you have a play with it a little.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot! 

Comment: It might be easier to think of it not so much as the Navigation Page is "on" the test page, but rather that the test page is pushed onto the navigation stack.  Then any pages you display off of that test page can be pushed and popped to/from the navigation stack.

Comment: Alright; but allow me to ask what the difference is between pushing and popping?